Generate Fig. 6.4 of Peter Corke's RVC 2nd Edition in Matlab
I want to generate the below Fig. 6.4 from Peter Corke's RVC 2nd Edition in Matlab.

I used the following code based on the example codes of the book.
 % 6.1.2. estimating pose

close all
clear
clc

V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);

veh = Bicycle('covar', V);

odo = veh.step(1, 0.3);

% veh.x'

veh.f([0 0 0], odo);

% veh.add_driver( RandomPath(10) )

% veh.run()

% veh.Fx( [0,0,0], [0.5, 0.1] )

P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);

ekf = EKF(veh, V, P0);

ekf.run(1000);

veh.plot_xy()
hold on
ekf.plot_xy('r')

% P700 = ekf.history(700).P

% sqrt(P700(1,1))

ekf.plot_ellipse('g')

% ekf.plot_P();

But, the following figure generated from my code is different. Could you please let me know my mistakes? Thank you.

